# how to solve errors: "excel range has bad size. it must be only 1 line or 1 row"

Tags: excel, csv, file, optimization, bigdata

how can I solve this error?
"excel range has bad size. it must be only 1 line or 1 row."  this error for large data from Cplex with  .csv  format occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to guess what happened but let me share a small csv OPL example:

.mod https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoocsv.mod

```
int nbKids=...;

// a tuple is like a struct in C, a class in C++ or a record in Pascal
tuple bus
{
  key int nbSeats;
  float cost;
}

// This is a tuple set
{bus} buses=...;

// asserts help make sure data is fine
assert forall(b in buses) b.nbSeats>0;
assert forall(b in buses) b.cost>0;

// decision variable array
dvar int+ nbBus[buses];

// objective
minimize
     sum(b in buses) b.cost*nbBus[b];
     
// constraints
subject to
{
   sum(b in buses) b.nbSeats*nbBus[b]>=nbKids;
}

tuple t_result
{
  key int nbSeats;
  int nb;
}

{t_result} result={<b.nbSeats,nbBus[b]> | b in buses};
```

.dat

/*

the csv file is https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoocsv.dat

```
nbseats;cost;
40;500;
30;400;

*/

nbKids=300;

// New feature in CPLEX 20.10

CSVConnection csvinput("zoobusesinput.csv?firstIsHeader=true", "");
buses from CSVRead(csvinput, "");

CSVConnection csvoutput("zoobusesoutput.csv?outputOnly=true&append=false&outputSeparator=;", "");
result to CSVPublish(csvoutput, "");
```

Comment: thanks. but how is it for a tuple with 4d? how I can define it?